# Cannot import Quartz.NET library for VB

Tags: vb.net, import, quartz.net

I have downloaded Quartz.NET and put it into the folder of my project. And I have also added `Quartz.NET\bin\Release\Quartz\net452\Quartz.dll` as reference. The import statements are:

```
Imports Quartz
Imports Quartz.Impl
```

(I just followed what I found in online tutorials and examples)

However, compiler error message appears for each import statement when I run the code:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Quartz' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

I have tried to remove the reference and add it again. It's fine before running, but error still occurred during compilation. Can anyone find out why does the error happen?

Comment: My bet would be that the downloaded dll is blocked by Windows Security. I'd recommend using the [Quartz.NET Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) instead.

Comment: @Filburt Which type of security setting do you mean?

Comment: If you inspect the properties of the Quartz.dll file, it will show an "Unblock" button if the file is blocked by Windows Security. Files coming from unsafe network locations are considered unsafe and are *blocked from execution*. In any case setting a reference to a library stored in the output folder isn't exactly best practice and using the Nuget package is a much cleaner way.

Comment: What type of project in Visual Studio have you created?  Check the target framework of your project.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks. I can find the "Unblock" button in the properties dialog of the file. However, the import is still prevented by another problem. I make a new question for the new found problem. You may refer to it: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945115/a-reference-to-quartz-dll-cannot-be-added-a-reference-to-the-component-quart)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm doing some task scheduling stuff so I need Quartz library to help with it.